# reading udf file system

Tags: kubuntu, filesystem, udf

Kubuntu 14.04 can mount and read a filesystem created with;

```
mkudffs --media-type=bdr
```

Kubuntu 18.04 can't.

A little more detail...

Using Kubuntu 18.04, 
If I create a filesystem with `mkudffs` without any parameters, and use `losetup`, Dolphin can mount it and read/write to it. However if I burn that `udf` filesystem to a blue-ray disk, everything looks great until I re-insert it. The system doesn't mount it and Dolphin sees it, but can't mount it. Error about bad fs type, codepage missing, etc.

If I create a filesystem with `mkudffs -media-type=bdr`, use `losetup`, Dolphin shows the filesystem, but when clicked on, can't mount or read/write to it.

When I use 14.04, everything works correctly.

I have downloaded `udftools`. Modprobe shows udf support.

mkudffs is NOT correctly creating a udf filesystem when using 18.04.

I copied mkudffs from my 14.04 to my 18.04 and it seems to work. Need to test it more thoroughly.

Comment: I have used `udf` file systems in USB drives, but not in optical media. Maybe `udftools` is not updated to work in newer versions of Ubuntu (and the Ubuntu flavour Kubuntu), and Ubuntu is developed without thinking of `udftools`. - A solution is to keep Kubuntu 14.04 LTS that still can do it (keep it alongside your current system or in a USB pendrive).

Comment: I read in `man mkudffs`: "LIMITATIONS
       mkudffs cannot create UDF 2.50 Metadata partition, therefore it does not support UDF revisions higher then 2.01 for non Write Once media yet. So there is no support for Blu-ray discs which needs UDF 2.50 (except  for  Blu-ray
       Disc Recordable which does not require Metadata partition)." Does this affect your use case?

Comment: Sudodus, Not sure what you mean when you say "So there is no support for Blu-ray discs which needs UDF 2.50". I'm using blank, BD-R disks to store data. However, I did burn several blu-ray disks of varying sizes using the OLD mkudffs program from my 14.04 computer copies to my 18.04 computer, and everything works as it should. I'm a very happy camper now, even after making a couple of coasters out of 50GB blu-ray disks. The newer version of mkudffs that is included in 18.04 DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: Well, it is not my words, but words from the manual of `mkudffs`. Your problem makes me surprised, but I think it is a bug (somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, sudodus. In my opinion, 14.04 was the best version ever. I've had a lot of problems getting 18.04 to work as smoothly as 14.04 did.I've been running 18.04 for about a year now, and still finding stuff like this.

Comment: Did you check if the same revision is used? You can force it with the option `-r,--udfrev= udf-revision`. Specify the UDF revision to use, either in hexadecimal (e.g. 0x0201)  or  decimal  (e.g. 2.01)  format.  Valid revisions arei 1.02, 1.50, 2.00, 2.01, 2.50 and 2.60.  If omitted, mkudffs udf-revision is 2.01, except for Blu-ray Discs  which  is  2.50.  UDF  revisions higher  then 2.01 are experimental. Option must be specified after --media-type. (Values in decimal format and revisions higher then 2.01 are supported since mkudffs 2.0)

Comment: No, I did no check if the same revision is used. I use my computers in order to get work done. I expect them to work without me having to 'experiment' to get them to work. In 1995, I switched from Windows to Linux, cold turkey, because I was fed up with the problems windows threw at me. I have used many different distros since then. In almost all cases, PClinuxOS and Kubuntu have worked for me flawlessly up until Kubuntu 18.04. This version has given me more problems to solve than all other versions combined.

Comment: I expect software to work. If it doesn't, just like any other equipment I purchase, I lose confidence in the company. 14.04 worked flawlessly 'out of the box' for me, just like almost all other distros over the years. I didn't have to figure out why something didn't work. I don't want to have to do that. Unfortunately, I've had to do that too often with 18.04. Why would they set mkudffs up with experimental revision? If I wanted an experimental distro, I'd go with another distro. I do want to thank you, very much for taking the time to try and help me. I really appreciate it.